Files Connect - One Drive - Mass Connect to Opportunity?
I have files connect enabled and set up and it's working great.  I'm now going into historical Opportunities and manually connecting historical files (not uploading the files - just connecting a reference) to the corresponding Opportunity.
Are there any programs or apps that can help me automate this process?  It's a manual process now.  It won't let me search by file so I'm scrolling and adding and it's taking a long time.
Open to all ideas.  Thanks!
